# Nested If statement moving through columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I have four columns of temperature data from four different sources (A-D). *Source A* is preferred over *B*, which is preferred over *C*, and so on. I'd like a new column to look through columns A-D to select the **best** temperature value. The problem is that there are many cells with no data (represented as -9999). I'd like to write a nested IF statement that will cycle through the cells to give me the best value in a new column. Seems fairly simple, my dataset is 20,000+.

> If A <>-9999, then A, if A = -9999, then B, if B =-9999, then C.

[image]

Comment: By **best** what do you mean? If I understand it correctly, as long as there's value in A, that would be the best, else you look in the next columns. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way with an array formula.  To enter this formula, hold down **ctrl+shift** while hitting **enter**.  If you did this correctly, Excel will place braces **{...}** around the formula in the formula bar:

```
=INDEX($A1:$D1,1,MATCH(TRUE,($A1:$D1<>-9999),0))
```